# Connecting scopes with braces and arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, braces, node-connections, scoping

I'm working in a tikz figure that so far is like that:

[image]

Produced with the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, calc, backgrounds, decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    blur/.style={preaction={draw,fill,white,opacity=.9,line width=2pt}},
    showdepth/.style={color=#1,ball color=#1,opacity=1+(\k-2)/5},
    edgemeta/.is choice,
    edgemeta/1/.style={blur,showdepth=green},
    edgemeta/2/.style={blur,showdepth=yellow},
    nodemeta/.is choice,
    nodemeta/0/.style={blur,showdepth=blue},
    nodemeta/1/.style={blur,showdepth=green},
    nodemeta/2/.style={blur,showdepth=yellow},
    drawedge_i/.style={drawedgex_i,drawedgey_i,drawedgez_i},
    % Input volume    
    drawedgex_i/.code={
        \ifnum\i=2\else
            \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\i+1),abs(\j),abs(\k)))}
            \draw[edgemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)--+(1,0,0);
        \fi
    },
    drawedgey_i/.code={
        \ifnum\j=2\else
            \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\j),abs(\j+1),abs(\k)))}
            \draw[edgemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)--+(0,1,0);
        \fi
    },
    drawedgez_i/.code={
        \ifnum\k=2\else
            \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\j),abs(\k),abs(\k+1)))}
            \draw[edgemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)--+(0,0,1);
        \fi
    },
    % Sublume
    drawedge_s/.style={drawedgex_s,drawedgey_s,drawedgez_s},
    drawedgex_s/.code={
        \ifnum\i=1\else
            \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\i+1),abs(\j),abs(\k)))}
            \draw[edgemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)--+(1,0,0);
        \fi
    },
    drawedgey_s/.code={
        \ifnum\j=1\else
            \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\j),abs(\j+1),abs(\k)))}
            \draw[edgemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)--+(0,1,0);
        \fi
    },
    drawedgez_s/.code={
        \ifnum\k=1\else
            \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\j),abs(\k),abs(\k+1)))}
            \draw[edgemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)--+(0,0,1);
        \fi
    },
    % Node
    drawnode/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\j),abs(\k)))}
        \shade[nodemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)circle(3pt);
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[z={(-.3,-.15)},draw=white,decoration={brace,amplitude=10}]
    \begin{scope}
            \foreach\k in{-2,...,2}{
                \foreach\j in{-2,...,2}{
                    \foreach\i in{-2,...,2}{
                        \path[drawedge_i,drawnode];
                    }
                }
        } 
        \coordinate (A) at (1,1,0); \coordinate (B) at (1,-1,0);
        \draw [decorate, red, thick] (A.north east) -- (B.south east);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
            \foreach\k in{-1,...,1}{
                \foreach\j in{-1,...,1}{
                    \foreach\i in{-1,...,1}{
                        \path[drawedge_s,drawnode];
                    }
                }
        }
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
            \foreach\k in{-1,...,1}{
                \foreach\j in{-1,...,1}{
                    \foreach\i in{-1,...,1}{
                        \path[drawedge_s,drawnode];
                    }
                }
        }
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm wondering how I could change the 'width' of the brace so it reaches the second image, or how to draw an arrow from it to connect these scopes, as here:

[image]

Also, I'm wondering how to connect to scopes with an arrow, as:

[image]

In this image, I used `\matrix(name)`, so I could simply do:

```
\draw [red, -latex, thick](A) -- (B)
```

For example.

Using scopes, I tried to do:

```
\begin{scope}[name=A]
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[name=B]
\end{scope}

\draw [red, -latex, thick](A) -- (B)
```

But I receive an error warning me that no shape with that names were found.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already learnt how to define `node`s while drawing the brace. Define some more of them and draw.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, calc, backgrounds, decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    blur/.style={preaction={draw,fill,white,opacity=.9,line width=2pt}},
    showdepth/.style={color=#1,ball color=#1,opacity=1+(\k-2)/5},
    edgemeta/.is choice,
    edgemeta/1/.style={blur,showdepth=green},
    edgemeta/2/.style={blur,showdepth=yellow},
    nodemeta/.is choice,
    nodemeta/0/.style={blur,showdepth=blue},
    nodemeta/1/.style={blur,showdepth=green},
    nodemeta/2/.style={blur,showdepth=yellow},
    drawedge_i/.style={drawedgex_i,drawedgey_i,drawedgez_i},
    % Input volume
    drawedgex_i/.code={
        \ifnum\i=2\else
            \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\i+1),abs(\j),abs(\k)))}
            \draw[edgemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)--+(1,0,0);
        \fi
    },
    drawedgey_i/.code={
        \ifnum\j=2\else
            \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\j),abs(\j+1),abs(\k)))}
            \draw[edgemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)--+(0,1,0);
        \fi
    },
    drawedgez_i/.code={
        \ifnum\k=2\else
            \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\j),abs(\k),abs(\k+1)))}
            \draw[edgemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)--+(0,0,1);
        \fi
    },
    % Sublume
    drawedge_s/.style={drawedgex_s,drawedgey_s,drawedgez_s},
    drawedgex_s/.code={
        \ifnum\i=1\else
            \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\i+1),abs(\j),abs(\k)))}
            \draw[edgemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)--+(1,0,0);
        \fi
    },
    drawedgey_s/.code={
        \ifnum\j=1\else
            \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\j),abs(\j+1),abs(\k)))}
            \draw[edgemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)--+(0,1,0);
        \fi
    },
    drawedgez_s/.code={
        \ifnum\k=1\else
            \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\j),abs(\k),abs(\k+1)))}
            \draw[edgemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)--+(0,0,1);
        \fi
    },
    % Node
    drawnode/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{int(max(abs(\i),abs(\j),abs(\k)))}
        \shade[nodemeta=\pgfmathresult](\i,\j,\k)circle(3pt);
    },
    mydeco/.style={decoration={brace,amplitude=#1},decorate}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[z={(-.3,-.15)},draw=white]
    \begin{scope}
            \foreach\k in{-2,...,2}{
                \foreach\j in{-2,...,2}{
                    \foreach\i in{-2,...,2}{
                        \path[drawedge_i,drawnode];
                    }
                }
        }
        \coordinate (A) at (1,1,0); \coordinate (B) at (1,-1,0);
        \draw [mydeco={10}, red, thick] (A.north east) -- (B.south east)node[coordinate,midway,right](C){};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
            \foreach\k in{-1,...,1}{
                \foreach\j in{-1,...,1}{
                    \foreach\i in{-1,...,1}{
                        \path[drawedge_s,drawnode];
                    }
                }
        }
        \coordinate (D) at (-1,0,0);
        \draw[red,-latex,shorten >= 5pt,shorten <= 10pt] (C) -- (D);
        \coordinate (E) at (1,1,0); \coordinate (F) at (1,-1,0);
        \draw [mydeco={10}, red, thick] (E.north east) -- (F.south east)node[coordinate,midway,right](G){};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
            \foreach\k in{-1,...,1}{
                \foreach\j in{-1,...,1}{
                    \foreach\i in{-1,...,1}{
                        \path[drawedge_s,drawnode];
                    }
                }
        }
        \coordinate (H) at (-1,0,0);
        \draw[red,-latex,shorten >= 5pt,shorten <= 10pt] (G) -- (H);
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just make sure that the dimension (10 here) in `mydeco={10}` and `shorten <= 10pt` are same.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I did yesterday after some reserach; I was wondering if I could connect the scopes in a 'magic' way as we can do when using \matrix. Thank you.